# Installer Missing from Downloads Page for Linux

Tags: leap-motion

It wasnt evident at first that you need the SDK and the installer to get leap motion working on Linux. That being said, the downloads page does show the download for the SDK but you need the SDK and installer which, according to said downloads page, has been removed in "anticipation of the consume launch" and to visit the setup page (http://leapmotion.com/setup) on July 22nd (today).

Therein lies the problem - there is no installer for Linux anymore which of course means no Debian packages to download and work with.

Does anyone have the old installer so that I may merely just get playing around with the leap motion while they correct this or am I in fact just doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

https://forums.leapmotion.com/showthread.php?2670-No-drivers

DavidH responded that there are no "release" driver, but the "beta" ones will be available at developer portal.